# How to get Date from Google Sheet and convert string to Date in Google Script to be used for createAllDayEvent?

Tags: google-apps-script

The goal is to create a variable in google script and create a calendar event. I'm using the following code:

```
var title = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Title")).getValue();
var startDate = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Date")).getValue();
var sDate = new Date("startDate");
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id).createAllDayEvent(title, sDate)
```

Everything works except the date is not converted to a Date for calendar event.

Comment: Variables shouldn't be quoted. Furthermore, `getValue()` already returns a date object. No need to create a new one.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the Code but it still brings back the wrong date.                                
   var sDate = new Date(startDate);

Comment: Try `createAllDayEvent(title, startDate)`

Comment: ITs fixed. The formatting in google sheets was causing the error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can add a answer explaining what helped for future readers with the same problem

Answer (score 2):

In order to pass a `date` value to the **Calendar** you should also check how you have stored the date in Google Sheets - more precisely in *which format*.

Moreover, if you want to `create` a new date you should create it like this:

```
var sDate = new Date(startDate);
```

You can also use the `formatDate` method in Apps Script if you want to format a date with the following parameters: `date`, `timeZone`, `format`.

**Reference**

- [Utilities Class Apps Script - formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))